# Can I say "My mom's kids names" to mean: "The names of my mother's kids"?

Tags: word-choice

As the tittle says it. Can I say "My mom's kids names" to mean:  "The names of my mother's kids" ?

Comment: Why not just "my siblings' names"?

Comment: @ArtOfCode +1 but, teeeeechnically, your mom's kids could be a mixture of your siblings, half-siblings and step-siblings, along with your mom's baby goats.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I was thinking about a word where my siblings and I are included.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I lived in the U.S.A and I always heard people refferring to their children and other people children as kids and I'm sure they weren't talking about baby goats at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not quite. It should be "my mom's kids' names." You need two apostrophes because there are two possessives here: The long form would be "the names of the kids of my mom."

Some people feel that chaining possessives in this manner is informal and would recommend rewriting it as "the names of my mom's kids." However, at least for informal language, people can (and do) chain possessives.

Comment: Note that "my mom's kids" would be your brothers and sisters (and half siblings). It might be easier to refer to them like that.

Comment: I also understand that that includes me. Am I right?

Comment: If you're going to accept "kids", you're either talking about baby goats or you're already at a level of informality where chaining possessives can't possibly be an issue.